# Does git apply --reject/--include use --verbose by default?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-patch, git-apply

I see

```
git apply --reject
git apply --include
```

always printing full info about which are files considered and rejected from patch file passed. So it seems `--verbose` mode used by git when `--reject` option passed.

Is `--verbose` option printing any other info that's not being printing by --reject option? I didn't find any relevant details in `git-apply` documentation too.

```
git apply --index change-89ded3243ea944156abb9d1c44173d998a4aed59..b3645cd3600b7d1c728c84333b48a20ce5c4eb29.patch
Done applying sandbox package.

git apply --reject change-89ded3243ea944156abb9d1c44173d998a4aed59..b3645cd3600b7d1c728c84333b48a20ce5c4eb29.patch
Checking patch support/gobuild/helpers/python.py...
Checking patch support/gobuild/helpers/target.py...
Checking patch support/gobuild/py/__init__.py...
Checking patch support/gobuild/py/autotools.py...
Checking patch support/gobuild/specs/cayman_pycrypto.py...
Checking patch support/gobuild/targets/cayman_pycrypto.py...
warning: support/gobuild/targets/cayman_pycrypto.py has type 100644, expected 100755
Applied patch support/gobuild/helpers/python.py cleanly.
Applied patch support/gobuild/helpers/target.py cleanly.
Applied patch support/gobuild/py/__init__.py cleanly.
Applied patch support/gobuild/py/autotools.py cleanly.
Applied patch support/gobuild/specs/cayman_pycrypto.py cleanly.
Applied patch support/gobuild/targets/cayman_pycrypto.py cleanly.
Done applying sandbox package.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--include` option has no effect on verbosity levels: it simply says that the patching process should apply changes to the named files, which of course implies that it should *not* apply changes to *other* files.  That is, a patch might mention files `this.txt`, `that.py`, and `README`.  If you say "include changes to `this.txt` and `README`" you are implying "please *don't* make any changes to `that.py`".

The `--verbose` option is actually a counter: used once, it raises the verbosity level from zero or "normal" to 1 or "verbose", and used twice it raises it beyond that.  However, there's no special action for higher numbers here (some Git commands do have multiple levels of verbosity, e.g., `git branch` has two).  There *is* a special negative-1 level but you cannot set that yourself (it's used automatically when `git am` applies multiple patches, with commits after each apply).

The `--reject` option automatically raises the verbosity level to at least 1.  Hence, internally, the sequence of options:

```
git apply --verbose --reject
```

means "set the verbosity level to 1, and also set the reject mode", while:

```
git apply --reject --verbose
```

means "set the verbosity level to 2, and also set the reject mode".

Long form options *longopt* usually allow the use of `no-longopt` to *clear* them.  (There are some exceptions, but this is not an exception.)  Therefore:

```
git apply --reject --no-verbose
```

will enable reject mode while setting the verbosity level back to zero ("normal" verbosity: some things are still printed).

Comment: Thx for explanation @torek